# matrix in a jeditorpane

Tags: java, html, swing, jeditorpane

i'm trying to "draw" a matrix in a jeditorpane.
i'm using this code:

```
public String addMatrix2(String a[][]){
    String text = "<table style=\"color:#000\"><tr><td><table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0px style=\"border-left:1px solid #000; border-right:1px solid #000; color:#000\"><tr>"+
    "<td style =\"border-top:1px solid #000; border-bottom:1px solid #000;\">&nbsp</td><td><table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 style=\"color:#000;\">";

    for(int i=0 ; i< a.length ; i++){
            text += "<tr>";
            for(int j=0 ; j<a[1].length ; j++){
                    text += "<td align=\"center\" valign=\"center\" width=30>"+a[i][j]+"</td>";
            }
            text += "</tr>";
    }
    text +="</table></td><td style =\"border-top:1px solid #000; border-bottom:1px solid #000;\">&nbsp</td></tr></table></td></tr></table>";
    //texto +=text;
    return text;
}
```

but it only shows the numbers, and no parentheses.

i'm triying to "draw" de cell boders and that way obtain the parantheses.
i don't figure out other way to get what i want :(

Comment: Where are the parentheses in your code that you are not seeing in the output?

Comment: An unrelated hint: If you use single quotes in the html, you avoid the backlinks: `text = "<table style='color:#000'>` ...

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: BTW - `\"color:#000\"` my understanding is that Java does not understand the 3 letter version of color specifications.  Does it actually paint as black?

Comment: BTW - Better change `j<a[1].length` to `j<a[i].length` or 0.

Comment: I'll probably suggest to use StringBuffer and append your html code than to string concatenation like in your question. This will provide clearer code. But I can take a look if you paste more of your codes.

Comment: @Jasonw: A StringBuilder is definitely *less* clear. Just faster at run time.